# Tweenmax js not stacking elements correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I've made a circular menu with sub-menu which for some reason doesn't stack on top of his parent.

```js
    function calcElementSemiCirc(element, radius){
        var testLInum = element.children.length;
        var startAngle = Math.PI / testLInum,
            angle = startAngle / 2,

            offset = 350;
        var test ={};
        if(radius==null) radius = 160;
        test.X =[];
        test.Y =[];
        for ( var i = 0; i < testLInum; i++ ) {
            var leftX = radius * Math.cos( angle ) + offset;
            var topY = radius * Math.sin( angle );
            angle += startAngle;
            test.X.push(leftX);
            test.Y.push(topY);
        }
        test.X.reverse();
        test.Y.reverse();
        return test;
    }
    var clickCount = 0; // <-- add this line
    var animationMain;
    var animationSub;
    var animationSecLvl;
    var animationMainSecLvl;
    document.getElementsByClassName("menu-open-button")[0].addEventListener("click", function () {

        clickCount++;
        var test = calcElementSemiCirc(document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item-wrap")[0], 160);
        if (clickCount === 2) clickCount = 0;

        if (clickCount === 1) {

            animationMain = TweenMax.to(".menu-item-wrap", 1, {delay:0,opacity: 1, zIndex:5, y:135, x:0, ease:Circ.easeOut, onComplete:someFunction}, 0.2);
            animationMain.duration(0.35);
            function someFunction() {
                animationSub = new TimelineMax();
                animationSub.set(".menu-item-wrap > li", {/*autoAlpha:0, left:0, */zIndex: 5});
                animationSub.to(".menu-item-wrap > li", 1, {delay:0,opacity: 1, zIndex:5, onReverseComplete:myFunction,
                    x: function(index, target) {
                        return test.X[index]-350;
                    },
                    y: function(index, target) {
                        return test.Y[index]-135;
                    }, ease:Elastic.easeOut, onComplete:function () {
//                        for(var u=0; u<document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item-wrap")[0].children.length;u++)
//                            document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item-wrap")[0].children[u].style.zIndex = 5;
//                            document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item-wrap")[0].children[0].style.opacity = 0.99;

                    }}, 0.2);
                animationSub.duration(1);
            }
            function myFunction(){
                animationMain.reverse();
            }
//            animationSecLvl = TweenMax.to(".menu-item-wrap > li > ul > li", 1, {delay:0,
//                x: function(index, target) {
//                    return test.X[index]-350;
//                },
//                y: function(index, target) {
//                    return test.Y[index]-135+25;
//                }, ease:Elastic.easeOut}, 0.2);

            document.getElementsByClassName("semi-circ")[0].style.minWidth = test.X[5]/1+"px";
            document.getElementsByClassName("semi-circ")[0].style.minHeight = test.X[5]/1+"px";
            //document.getElementsByClassName("semi-circ")[0].style.minHeight = test.Y[2]+80+"px";
            document.getElementsByClassName("semi-circ")[0].style.left = -test.X[5]+(test.X[5]/2)+40+"px";
            document.getElementsByClassName("semi-circ")[0].style.top = -test.X[5]/1.8+"px";
        }
        if (clickCount === 0) {
            animationSub.reverse().timeScale(1.25);
        }
    });

    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item-wrap")[0].children;
    var test;
    var clickCountSecLvl = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
        list[j].addEventListener("click", function (e) {

            var elements;
            if (e.target == this) {
                console.log("this");
                console.log(e.target.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0]);
                elements = e.target.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
            }
            else{
                console.log("not this");
                console.log(e.target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0]);
//                console.log(e.target.parentNode.parentNode);
                elements = e.target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
                console.log(e.target);
            }
            window.test = calcElementSemiCirc(elements, 85);

            clickCountSecLvl++;

            if (clickCountSecLvl === 2) clickCountSecLvl = 0;

            if (clickCountSecLvl === 1) {
                var elements2 = elements.getElementsByTagName("li");
                animationMainSecLvl = TweenMax.to(elements, 1, {
                    delay: 0,
                    opacity: 1, zIndex:10,
                    y: 135,
                    x: 0,
                    ease: Elastic.easeOut
                }, 0.2);
                animationSecLvl = TweenMax.to(elements2, 1, {
                    delay: 0,
                    opacity: 1, zIndex:10,
                    x: function (index, target) {
                        return test.X[index] - 350+((index+1));
                    },
                    y: function (index, target) {
                        return test.Y[index] - 135 + 55/*(elements2.length-(index+1))*/;
                    },
                    ease: Elastic.easeOut
                }, 0.2);
            }
            if (clickCountSecLvl === 0) {
                animationMainSecLvl.reverse();
                animationSecLvl.reverse();
            }
        });


    }
```

```css
body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            background: #596778;
            color: #EEEEEE;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
            body {
                padding: 170px 0 0 0;
                width: 100%
            }
        }

        a {
            color: inherit;
        }

        .menu-item-wrap{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: #EEEEEE;
            position: absolute;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .menu-item {
        }

        .menu-item,
        .menu-open-button,
        .menu-overlay{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: #EEEEEE;
            border-radius: 100%;
            min-width: 80px;
            min-height: 80px;
            position: absolute;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 80px;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        .menu-open {
            display: none;
        }

        .lines {
            width: 25px;
            height: 3px;
            background: #596778;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -12.5px;
            margin-top: -1.5px;
            -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms;
            transition: -webkit-transform 200ms;
            transition: transform 200ms;
            transition: transform 200ms, -webkit-transform 200ms;
        }

        .line-1 {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -8px, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -8px, 0);
        }

        .line-2 {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }

        .line-3 {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 8px, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 8px, 0);
        }

        .menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button .line-1 {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(45deg);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(45deg);
        }

        .menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button .line-2 {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0.1, 1);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0.1, 1);
        }

        .menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button .line-3 {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(-45deg);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(-45deg);
        }

        .menu {
            /*margin: auto;*/
            position: relative;
            top: -180px;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 50%;
            right: 50%;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            text-align: center;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-size: 26px;
        }

        .semi-circ{
            position: absolute;border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;

        }
        /* .menu-item {
           transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
        } */

        .menu-item:hover {
            background: #EEEEEE;
            color: #3290B1;
        }

        .menu-open-button {
            z-index: 2;
            -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
            transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
            -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
            transition-duration: 400ms;
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            cursor: pointer;
            box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
            left: 0;
        }

        .menu-open-button:hover {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }

        .blue {
            background-color: #669AE1;
            box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
        }

        .blue:hover {
            color: #669AE1;
            text-shadow: none;
        }

        .green {
            background-color: #70CC72;
            box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
        }

        .green:hover {
            color: #70CC72;
            text-shadow: none;
        }

        .red {
            background-color: #FE4365;
            box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
        }

        .red:hover {
            color: #FE4365;
            text-shadow: none;
        }

        .purple {
            background-color: #C49CDE;
            box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
        }

        .purple:hover {
            color: #C49CDE;
            text-shadow: none;
        }

        .orange {
            background-color: #FC913A;
            box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
        }

        .orange:hover {
            color: #FC913A;
            text-shadow: none;
        }

        .lightblue {
            background-color: #62C2E4;
            box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
        }

        .lightblue:hover {
            color: #62C2E4;
            text-shadow: none;
        }

        li{
            list-style: none;
        }
        .menu-item-wrap ul, .menu-item-wrap ul li{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        /*max-height: 0;*/
        /*overflow: hidden;*/
            opacity: 0;
        }
        .semi-circ{
            background-color: #3290B1;
        }
        .menu-open-button{
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 555;
        }
        .menu-item-wrap > li{
            position: absolute;
            z-index: -5;
        }
        .menu-overlay{
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 6;
        }
        .menu-item-wrap > li > ul{
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 5;
        }
        .menu-item-wrap > li > ul > li{
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 10!important;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.4/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="menu">
    <div class="semi-circ"></div>
    <input type="checkbox" href="#" class="menu-open" name="menu-open" id="menu-open" />
    <label class="menu-open-button" for="menu-open">
        <span class="lines line-1"></span>
        <span class="lines line-2"></span>
        <span class="lines line-3"></span>
    </label>
    <ul class="menu-item-wrap">
        <li class="menu-item blue"><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i> </a></li>
        <li class="menu-item green"><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i> </a>
            <ul>
                <li class="menu-item red"><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> </a></li>
                <li class="menu-item purple"><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-microphone"></i> </a></li>
                <li class="menu-item orange"><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> </a></li>
                <li class="menu-item lightblue"><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> </a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="menu-overlay"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item red"><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> </a></li>
        <li class="menu-item purple"><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-microphone"></i> </a></li>
        <li class="menu-item orange"><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> </a>
            <ul>
                <li class="menu-item red"><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> </a></li>
                <li class="menu-item purple"><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-microphone"></i> </a></li>
                <li class="menu-item orange"><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> </a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="menu-overlay"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item lightblue"><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> </a></li>

    </ul>
</nav>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The white ones are the ones with the sub menus. When clicked the right one behaves correctly but the left one is behind its parent element instead of in front. I've searched for an answer but I can't find anything.

Strangely it does work when I use the development tools in the browser and change the z-index inline in the HTML manually to a lower value but it doesn't work programmatically.